# R compose datatable using ifelse statment

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization, apply

I am trying perform a comparison on each row of a datatable and then extract a row from another table based on the result of the comparison. If the index that is to be looked up is greater than the length of the lookup table then a calculation needs to be performed. Here is what I have. The table I am iterating over is `Indicators` and looks like the following

```
Row, Val.A, Val.B
1,   30,    20.0
2,   3,     40.0
3,   1,     100.0
...
```

The table I am looking up rows from is `Loading` and looks like this:

```
Index, Zone.A, Zone.B, Zone.C, Zone.D, Zone.E
1,     10.0,   20.0,   1.00,   23.0,   34.5
2,     20.0,   40.0,   10.0,   34.5,   54.0
3,     40.0,   100.0,  100.0,  67.8,   98.2
...
10,    10.0,   10.0,   10.0,   10.0,   10.0
```

What I am trying to do is use `ifelse()` or `apply()` for this problem but it is not working. The goal is to look up the row in the `Loading` table which corresponds to the value of `Val.A` in the `Indicators` table and to perform a calculation when there is no data in `Loading`. The code I am trying to use for this is the following:

```
max.index <- max(Loading[,1])
result <- ifelse(Indicators$Val.A < max.index, 
     Loading[[Indicators$Val.A,2:6]], 
     Loading[[max.index,2:6]] * Indicators$Val.A
```

)

Using the data shown the goal result for `Indicators` would be:

```
Zone.A, Zone.B, Zone.C, Zone.D, Zone.E
300.0,  300.0,  300.0,  300.0,  300.0
40.0,   100.0,  100.0,  67.8,   98.2
10.0,   20.0,   1.00,   23.0,   34.5
```

The first row lies outside of the available rows in the `Loading` table so it is calculated but the other rows of `Indicators` have values contained in the `Loading` table so those rows are just looked up. Thanks for any help you can provide. R often confuses me with its iteration and vector operations.

Comment: Isn't `Loading[[max.index,2:6]] * Indicators$Val.B = 200`, not 300 as in your example??

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected.

Comment: Edited my answer to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
z <- merge(Indicators,Loading,by.x="Val.A",by.y="Index",all.x=T)
z[is.na(z$Zone.A),4:8] <- Loading[nrow(Loading),2:6]*z[is.na(z$Zone.A),]$Val.A
z
#   Val.A Row Val.B Zone.A Zone.B Zone.C Zone.D Zone.E
# 1     1   3   100     10     20      1   23.0   34.5
# 2     3   2    40     40    100    100   67.8   98.2
# 3    30   1    20    300    300    300  300.0  300.0
```

The basic idea is to merge `Loadings` into `Indicators` using `Indicators$Val.A` and `Loading$Index`, keeping all columns from `Indicators`. Absent a match, `Zone.A - Zone.E` in the result will be NA. So now we select only those rows with `Zone.A=NA` and fill using your second rule.

This does assume the Loadings is sorted on Index (so the last row has max(Index)).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. I'm slowly starting to understand the R way of doing things. Examples  like this really help.